# Returning multiple partial views on single AJAX call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I know this question has been asked many time before, but I believe my scenario is a little different and I am just looking for the best way to handle it.

I have 3 Partial Views and 3 corresponding ViewModels. One for Category, Division and Product.

A Category contains a collection of Divisions.. and a Division contains a collection of Products.

In my main view, I call RenderPartial on the 3 partial views...

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_Categories", Model.Categories); }
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_Divisions", Model.Divisions); }
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_Products", Model.Products); }
```

and I use jQuery to update the respective partial views as the selected category, division and product change.

Now here is where the problem is... When I select a category, I update the divisions section with the divisions for that category.. But what I would also like to do is to update the products section based on the first division in the collection since initially no division is selected.

I came up with a few different options to handle this, and I am not sure what is the best approach...

1. I could wait until my first AJAX call returns with the collection of divisions, and then do a second AJAX call to update the products.. I do not want to do this however for obvious performance considerations
2. I could structure my partial views such that, the Category partial view, contains the Division partial view, and the Division partial view contains the Products partial view. This way when my category changes, I can update the Products with one AJAX call. The problem that I have with this is that.. all the static HTML that will be defined in between my divisions and products partial views will be passed on every AJAX call.
3. I could modify my AJAX call to return a JSON object containing all the models and update the views client side.. however, I quite like the flexibility of being able to modify how the views are rendered in the server.. rather than concatenating a bunch of html on the client side.

If I could return multiple partial views via one AJAX call, then this would solve my problem. However, if there is something that I am doing wrong architecturally, I would gladly change it. Any advice? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

A 4th option is to return a razor view with the ContentType set to text/javascript as the response. Razor will render the partial views, but then the browser will execute the javascript to update the DOM.

You'll have to make sure your ajax call is done correctly so that it executes the response.

```
$("#Categories").html('@Html.RenderPartial("_Categories", Model.Categories)')
$("#Divisions").html('@Html.RenderPartial("_Divisions", Model.Divisions)')
$("#Products").html('@Html.RednerPartial("_Products", Model.Products)')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, this will still require that I wait for the initial ajax call to return before making the other 3 ajax calls.. is that a bad practice? Is there a problem with my design that is making this a difficult problem?

Comment: When the user changes the category, make an ajax request to fetch the divisions for that category. On the server side, store not only the divisions in the ViewModel, but also the products for the first division. Your controller action then returns the view as described in the answer. In your view code you will write the `js` above. Asp.net MVC will replace the string in the `.html()` with the actual html response from each partial. Only then will that response be sent to the client. The client is basically getting executable js code and your respective sections are filled in one ajax call.

Comment: @ntsue, you may have already figured out on your own, what I just said. However, I wanted to say it out loud, so in case there is anything wrong with my understanding of it, BZink can correct me ... :)

Comment: Yes. that's right. I meant to come back to this with complete code, but I forgot :)

Comment: @Amith George, Thanks!! I actually did misread the proposed solution.